# I have a Clipping class in css that work only in the chrome and did not work in firefox and internet explorer, how can i fix it?

Tags: css

**here the css**
I used search for my problem, but I couldn't find any similar question. I have prblem with CSS on Firefox. "clip-path:" doesn't show.

```css
    .clip {
       /* PLACE IN THE BEFORE AREA */
content:"";
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
display: block;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;

background-color: rgba(58, 60, 69, .6);
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 100% 90%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%, 0 90%);
        clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 100% 90%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%, 0 90%);
        }
```

Comment: There is a space in the `-web` - `kit-...`  that shouldn't be there... also - this could be a more simplified example to get to the bottom of things.

Comment: I know that, but it's not this problem

Comment: Either way - it is A problem.

Comment: What is it 100% height of? If your parent doesn't have a height... then your .clip element will have no reference - and not have a height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimum viable example: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/d30dpveh/

List of browsers and versions you can expect this to be applied: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path  (no Microsoft support)

More docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

markup

```
<div class="thing"></div>
```

styles

```
.thing {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 100% 90%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%, 0 90%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 100% 90%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%, 0 90%);
}
```

Whenever possible - you can try something like 'autoprefixer' to automatically add the prefixes for you - and ensure that moz and webkit etc area all added when they need to be there.